# Moderncv package with multicols set vertical space

Tags: spacing, lists, multicol, moderncv

I am currently finishing my CV using the moderncv package. To save space I decided to fit all my interests in a multicol environment with 4 columns nested inside an itemize environment.
Unfortunately, I get an additional white line after the multicol package that forces my CV to reach 3 pages.

I am already using the command

```
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
```

globally and this deleted the vertical white space before the multicol environment, but after I still get an additional white line.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% MODERNCV THEME
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

% CHARACTER ENCODING
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% ADJUST THE PAGE MARGINS
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{myset}{
        encoding = T1,
        family = {sf*,rm*},
        font = {T1/tt*/m/n/*,
                    T1/tt*/m/it/*} }
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{myset}

\moderncvicons{awesome}% New icons fontawesome

\usepackage{textcomp}% Adds star as a birthday symbol

\usepackage{multicol}%Usage: \begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%Takes space before and after the multicolumn

\newcommand{\localtextbulletone}{\textcolor{color1}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}}%Changes Item List bullet size and color
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\localtextbulletone}%Sets the new bullet type

\begin{document}

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{Italian}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Advanced}{European Level: C1; IELTS: 7.5}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Self Assesment: B1}
\cvitemwithcomment{Portuguese}{Basic}{Self Assesment: A2}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 (Long item, Long item)\vspace{0.67pt}
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \item Item 5
    \item Item 6
    \item Item 7
    \item Item 8
    \item Item 9
\end{multicols}
\end{itemize}
}

\section{Referees}
\end{document}
```

and this is the output:[image]

As you can see the vertical spacing after the interests section is higher than the spacing in between the languages and interests section.
Also,

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

is not an option since it completely modifies all the spaces.

Is there any way I can delete this additional vertical space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick fix is to add some negative vertical space, i.e.

```
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
```

immediately after `\end{multicols}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose your `itemize` environment inside a minipage:

```
\cvitem{}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 (Long item, Long item)\vspace{0.67pt}
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \item Item 5
    \item Item 6
    \item Item 7
    \item Item 8
    \item Item 9
\end{multicols}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without Item 1 and with a non-empty cvitem first argument, this messes up the cvitem vertical positioning.